# What breaks this code from PHP 5.2 to 5.4

Tags: php, forms, post, curl

```
<?php
$values = '';

foreach($_REQUEST  as $key => $val) {
    $values .= $key.'='.$val.'&';
}

$url = 'https://someurl.com';

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $values);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

echo ($response);

?>
```

Something is breaking this code between PHP 5.2 and 5.4, I'm not entirely sure what. I've been able to verify that the request variables exist, and that values is correct after the foreach loop. However it appears the issue is with the CURL , as the response does not echo. I receive no errors, and nothing is returned as if the curl does not return a response.

Comment: Are you sure the cURL extension is installed under 5.4?

Comment: I checked via phpinfo and curl was enabled, I believe it was version 7 something.

Comment: What errors do you get? Turn errors on.

Comment: Possibly curl (or someurl.com) objects to the spurious `&` at the end of your post fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: What does this setting do? This fixed my issue although I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: It turns off ssl certificate verification. Either the certificate is self signed, expired, or curl does not recognize the certificate authority.